# Regex to find and match &amp (Both Cases - present and not) and clean it

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to extract title's from web pages using regex, however some of the title's have &amp which is causing my regex not to match. I am completely new to regex. Plus while searching I came across this stackoverflow so though of asking the questions here. (I read through all the similar content and youtube video's on regex but non address my issues, hence I am asking this question here)

This is my already written regex

```
match = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+(&amp)) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>', s).groups()
```

My code:

```
s = """HTML source """
#https://ipinfo.io/AS7018  [This is the webpage i am trying to scrape]

match = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>', s)
if match:
    asn_code, name = match.groups()
    print(asn_code)
    print(name)
```

This is not matching even the titles that do not have &amp
sample webpages:
https://ipinfo.io/AS7922
https://ipinfo.io/AS7018

Expected Output:
Comcast Cable Communications, LLC  United States
AT&T Services, Inc. United States

I am not sure how to change my regex part(?=&amp) to match both &amp as well as NOT &amp
Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to match what? `ipinfo.com`?

Comment: there are lots of elements with h3 check here https://regex101.com/r/pSmgGC/1/, ` Comcast Cable Communications,` only this name is under h3 not the other names you specified

Comment: Yes, from the other web-page I need to get the AT&T Services, Inc . since it has a &amp I am not able to match it.

Comment: I have given 2 different web pages and I am trying to get the titles from each of those. website 1: https://ipinfo.io/AS7018    website 2:  https://ipinfo.io/AS7922

Comment: <title>AS7018 AT&amp;T Services, Inc. - IPinfo IP Address Geolocation API</title>  this is what i am tryint to match

Comment: `[\w.\s]+`  matches only `_A-Za-z0-9. \t\n` missing at least `&;,-` not that `-` must be the first last character or escaped `\-` otherwise used to set range, [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pSmgGC/3)

Comment: You may be better off using [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) rather than regex (or potentially combined with some simpler regex depending on the complexity of your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions.  Use a suitable HTML parser.  Here's an example with `BeautifulSoup` using `html.parser` from the standard library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import bs4
import requests


def main():
    response = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS7018')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    asn_code, _, name = soup.h3.text.partition(' ')
    print('ASN code:', asn_code, '  Company name:', name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```